# pandas - best way to iterate over year-week-day index for fast performance

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a typical financial dataframe with 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Mean' and 'Volume' columns, 1 min frequency (1.2M rows/df, 500+ df).

I need to iterate over this dataframe by year, inside year by weeks, inside weeks by day.

Some code of what I've done until today:

```
 import os
 import pandas as pd


 for file in os.listdir(data_path):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):

        df = pd.read_csv(data_path + file, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
        df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']  # ranamed the Date_Time column
        df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
        df['Mean'] = round(df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']].mean(axis=1), 2)

        df['Year'] = [0] * len(df)
        df['Week'] = [0] * len(df)
        df['Day'] = [0] * len(df)
        for i in range(len(df)):
            df['Year'][i] = df['Timestamp'][i].isocalendar()[0]
            df['Week'][i] = df['Timestamp'][i].isocalendar()[1]
            df['Day'][i] = df['Timestamp'][i].isocalendar()[2]

        index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['Year'], df['Week'], df['Day']], names = ['Year','Week','Day'])

        # build a new df from df with index as MultiIndex and save it in .hdf format
```

Then I used this 3-levels index to access data with 3 for loops in the following way:

```
# years cycle
years_array = asset.data.index.levels[0].values
for year in years_array:

    # weeks cycle
    weeks_array = np.array(np.unique(asset.data.loc[year].index.labels[0] + 1))
    for week in weeks_array:

        week0 = asset.data.loc[year, week].Open.values
        mean0 = np.mean(week0)

        if week != weeks_array[-1]:
            week1_year = year
            week1_week = week + 1
        elif (week == weeks_array[-1]) & (year != years_array[-1]):
            week1_year = year + 1
            week1_week = 1
        elif (week == weeks_array[-1]) & (year == years_array[-1]):
            break

        # minutes cycle
        week1 = asset.data.loc[week1_year, week1_week].Open.values
        for minute in range(len(week1)):
           # do da magic stuff...
```

There's is a smarter way for doing this? This is StackOverflow, so I'm pretty sure that there's a smarter way.

What I really need is to easily get the **previous week** (week0 in my code)data, based on my current locaction in the **current week** (week1 in my code).

Thank you for all the help!